# how to solve the "type mismatch" and "unresolved reference" errors when converting MainActivity to a fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I'm trying to convert my MainActivity.kt into a Fragment, so the beggining of the code looks like this so far:

```
class MainActivity : Fragment() {
lateinit var mAdView : AdView    private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog
private var selectedtype = "Ultra fast"
private val binding by lazy {
    ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}



override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity, container, false)
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    //setContentView(binding.root)
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false)
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    inIt()
    MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
    mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView)
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
    
    getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
    getSupportActionBar()?.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_title)

}
```

I have this error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but Context! was expected

Here:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
```

and here:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
```

and this error:

> Unresolved reference: getSupportActionBar

here:

```
getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
getSupportActionBar()?.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_title)
```

how can I solve those?

Answer (score 0):

An `Activity` is different from a `Fragment`. You cannot simply change `AppCompatActivity` into `Fragment`.

To get back the corresponding `Activity` from a `Fragment`, you have to use `getActivity()`.

So for,

> progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)

You should have:

```kotlin
progressDialog = ProgressDialog(activity)
```

And for:

> getSupportActionBar()?...

You should have:

```kotlin
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar...
```

Note that your `Activity` should be an `AppCompatActivity` in order to use `getSupportActionBar()`.